# Counting Bytes sent/received over HTTP

Tags: java, http, byte, counter

In Java,
How could the bytes sent and received over an active HTTP connection be counted?
I want to display some statistics like:

```
Bytes Sent     : xxxx Kb   
Bytes Received : xxxx Kb  
Duration       : hh:mm
```

Comment: What mechanism are you using? HttpURLConnection? And do you need the bytes received/sent to include the headers or just the body?

Comment: Actually, I actually want to do this in Java ME but I didn't receive any answers for that so I modified my question for Java SE thinking i could somehow workaround.  Well JavaME has the HttpConnection Interface http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/

Comment: I would like to include all the bytes because I am calculating cost depending on bytes sent and received over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to see how you could decorate [HttpConnection](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) to count the raw byte data. You could reimplement HTTP using sockets, but this would have to be pretty important to go to those lengths.

Sample response from `stackoverflow.com`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Mon, 21 Sep 2009 11:46:48 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2009 11:46:48 GMT
Content-Length: 19452

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>...remaining data....
```

HTTP requests are reasonably simple, so you might try reconstructing it using the information that is exposed. Something of the form:

```
// TODO: edge cases, error handling, header delimiter, etc.
int byteCount = 0;
int headerIndex = 0;
while (true) {
  String key = httpConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(headerIndex);
  if (key == null)
    break;
  String value = httpConnection.getHeaderField(headerIndex++);
  byteCount += key.getBytes("US-ASCII").length
      + value.getBytes("US-ASCII").length + 2;
}
byteCount += httpConnection.getHeaderFieldInt("Content-Length",
    Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

That implementation is incomplete and untested. You'd need to study up on the details of the [HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) to ensure the accuracy of your results.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the HTTPURLConnection's getInputStream() and getOutputStream() in your own streams that count the bytes that go through them. Or even better use the Apache Commons IO library - they have counting stream implementations in there.

Comment: reading Input output stream won't count HEADER length. The count will be always lesser than original. Rather One should see bytes used in http connection in WIRESHARK (for sampling)